# Measuring a speed in Kelvin $K$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, units, dimensional-analysis, speed

Since the Kelvins are a temperature unit and temperature is basically molecule/atoms excitation (so they have a "speed of excitation"), could it be possible to measure a speed (let's say 10 meters per second) in Kelvins?

Comment: This is the concept behind *thermal velocity*, which describes the average speed of certain molecules at a particular temperature. You wouldn't typically do an analysis in reverse though, to find the "temperature" of an object that has some macroscopic translational velocity.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of, you also need to take the mass of the particles into account (temperature can classically be thought of as vibrational energy, which scales with mass). The equation you're looking for (for a gas) is:
$$
v_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M_m}}
$$
Where $R$ is the gas constant, $M_m$ is the molar mass and $v_{RMS}$ is the root-mean square speed of the molecules in your gas, e.g. the square root of the average of the square of the velocity:
$$v_{RMS} = \sqrt{\overline{v^2}}$$